# WebGL alpha blending with depth

Tags: webgl

How to correctly blend two half opaqued faces in WebGL, as shown in the diagram?

[image: Diagram of intersecting faces]

Comment: Please post some code, showing what you tried and why it didn't work. It will be much easier for someone to help you if they have more context as to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *normal* way to do this is you have to split those 2 faces into 4 faces, sort them by depth and draw them furthest to nearest.

There's another technique, [depth peeling](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10/opengl/src/dual_depth_peeling/doc/DualDepthPeeling.pdf) but it's also fairly complicated.

There's also [order independent transparency](http://casual-effects.blogspot.jp/2015/03/implemented-weighted-blended-order.html).

Both of these last techniques are probably better suited for WebGL2